# How can I prove that modul of this vector bigger than radius of a circle?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let be $A$, $B$, $C$ be three points on the semicircle with diameter $PQ=2$ ($O$ is center) . Prove that modul of vector $\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OC}$ bigger than 1.

I tried prove that $\widehat{COD}$ is an acute. But it false.

In this picture, $\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}=\overrightarrow{OD}$ and $\overrightarrow{OD}+\overrightarrow{OC}=\overrightarrow{OE}.$ And I only consider $B$ is between $A$ and $C$.

(I am sory because in picture, semicircle was drawn a circle). 
[image]

Comment: Please define $D$ and $E$.  Is $D=A+B$ and $E=D+C$?

Comment: The modulus is invariant under rotation. If you rotate the configuration $A,B,C$ so that $\angle AOP = \angle QOC$, what can you say about $\overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{OC}$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

This is soulution of my friend.

WOLG, we can suppose $B$ is between $A$ and $C$. Let $\overrightarrow{OD}= \overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OC}$ and $\overrightarrow{OE}= \overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OD}$. We have $\widehat{AOC} \leqslant 180^\circ$, therefore $\widehat{AOD} \leqslant 90^\circ$ and $\widehat{DOC} \leqslant 90^\circ$. Thus $\angle BOD$ is an acute (or right).  Therefore $\vert \overrightarrow{OB} + \overrightarrow{OD}\vert > OB = 1.$

[image]